# how to print the digits from a string from the end to the beginning separated by commas in python?

Tags: python

can someone please help me? 
my input is a list of two strings. each string is a four digits number. I need to take the two strings. and print each's digits from the end to the beginning separated by commas, but without a comma after the last digit.
thanks (:

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's customary to try and solve the problem yourself first and share the code you tried. Hint: The `split` method might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can just concatenate the strings and use the `join()` method.

```
> s1 = '1234'
> s2 = '5678'
> print(','.join(s1 + s2))
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'
```

Comment: I need to print it this way:
s1 = '1234'
s2 = '5678'
 so it should be:
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8

Comment: @R.Amit Add your expected output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
In[2]: two_strings = ['1234', '5678']
In[3]: for elem in two_strings:
  ...:     print(','.join(elem))
  ...: 
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```